# Can't send a FileStream on to AWS when posting with route param (works fine without)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await, asp.net-core-mvc, aws-sdk

Using ASP.NET Core v.2.1.2 with AWSSDK for S3 ( version 3.3.20.2)

Same controller, two different routes (one with url param and one without). The methods are identical except the one with the url param has an argument. I want to upload a file but then send it on to S3( and that works fine in the no-param case).

Just adding the id argument causes the request to aws to time out with error:

`"Your socket connection to the server was not read from or written to within the timeout period. Idle connections will be closed."`

This is the failing request:

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:5000/api/post/image/4 \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: c78c7572-8822-4de7-a532-61538df87c85' \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' \
  -F =@/Users/myusername/Desktop/peace.png
```

I guess adding the id param changes the HttpContext.Request.Body but I can't see that change when I run in debug and add breakpoints (the stream looks exactly the same)

What am I missing here? The identical code but with the id param removed works for both routes

By the way the reason I want the id param in there is so that, once the file is uploaded, I can record the file id on the post as a reference to the record in AWS

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using BlogApi.Models;
using BlogApi.Services;

namespace BlogApi.Controllers
{
  [Route("api/[controller]")]
  [ApiController]

  public class PostController : ControllerBase
  {
    public string AWS_KEY {get; private set;}
    public string AWS_SECRET {get; private set;}
    private readonly PostContext _context;
    private AmazonUploader uploader { get; set; }

    public PostController(PostContext context)
    {
      _context = context;
      AWS_KEY = "my_key";
      AWS_SECRET = "my_secret";
      uploader = new AmazonUploader(AWS_KEY, AWS_SECRET);
    }

    [HttpPost("image/{id}")]
    public string Image(long id)
    {
      var request = HttpContext.Request;
      var fileStream = request.Body;
      var contentLength = request.ContentLength;
      var contentType = request.ContentType;
      string key = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

      var length = contentLength.HasValue ? (long)contentLength : 0;
      return uploader.sendMyFileToS3(fileStream, contentType, length, key).Result;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public string MyFileUpload()
    {
      var request = HttpContext.Request;
      var fileStream = request.Body;
      var contentLength = request.ContentLength;
      var contentType = request.ContentType;
      string key = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

      var length = contentLength.HasValue ? (long)contentLength : 0;
      return uploader.sendMyFileToS3(fileStream, contentType, length, key).Result;
    }
...
```

Just for info here is the code for my AmazonUploader class

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using Amazon;
using Amazon.S3;
using Amazon.S3.Model;
using Amazon.S3.Transfer;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace BlogApi.Services
{
  public class AmazonUploader
  {
    private IAmazonS3 client;
    private const string bucketName = "my_bucket"; 
    private static readonly RegionEndpoint bucketRegion = RegionEndpoint.EUWest2;

    public AmazonUploader(string AWS_KEY, string AWS_SECRET) {
      client = new AmazonS3Client(AWS_KEY, AWS_SECRET, bucketRegion);
    }

    public async Task<ListObjectsResponse> ListingObjectsAsync()
    {            
        ListObjectsRequest request = new ListObjectsRequest
        {
            BucketName = bucketName
        };
        return await client.ListObjectsAsync(request);
    }
    public async Task<string> sendMyFileToS3(System.IO.Stream inputStream, string contentType, long contentLength, string key)
    {
      PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest
      {
        BucketName = bucketName,
        Key = key,
        ContentType = contentType,
        InputStream = inputStream 
      };
      request.Headers.ContentLength = contentLength;
      PutObjectResponse awsResponse = await client.PutObjectAsync(request);
      if (awsResponse.HttpStatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) {
          return key;
      } else {
          return "error";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what url do you call for the one that does not work?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I post to http://localhost:5000/api/post/image/4 and if I set a breakpoint inside the method it is triggered

Comment: I've added the curl for the failing request to the question

Comment: I suggest reviewing and comparing the raw requests of the one that works and the one that doesn't.

Comment: Just out of interest - how would you do that? When I set the breakpoints I can't work out how to 'see' the stream. The Body objects seem identical.

In any case, thanks for your help, I just found the problem which was a) I made a stupid mistake and somehow had Postman adding a header of `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-encoded` and b) even if I hadn't added that header by mistake, the content-type was wrong - I was sending as `multipart/form-data` which doesn't work - I needed to send it as binary. If I select that option for the Body of the request in Postman it works.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the problem which was

a) I made a mistake and somehow had Postman adding an extra header of Content-Type: application/x-www-form-encoded

b) even if I hadn't added that header by mistake, the actual content-type was wrong - I was sending as multipart/form-data which doesn't work - I needed to send it as binary. If I select that option for the Body of the request in Postman it works.